# transposition of verticalProgress in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, progress

have anyone seen something that we can call horizontalProgress in Shiny? I found function verticalProgress which is almost perfect for my, unfortunately I need to transposition it. Maybe how to help my? Maybe using CSS?

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPagePlus(
      header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
        enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
        rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
      ),
      sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
      body = dashboardBody(
        verticalProgress(
          value = 20,
          status = "danger",
          size = "xs",
          height = "60%"
        )
      ),
      rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
      title = "Right Sidebar"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` in the style :

```
    div(style="display: inline-block; transform: rotate(10deg);",verticalProgress(
      value = 20,
      status = "danger",
      size = "xs",
      height = "60%"
    ))
```

Alternatively you can use `shinyWidgets` library which has `progressBar`

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinydashboardPlus)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPagePlus(
      header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
        enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
        rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
      ),
      sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
      body = dashboardBody(

        column(2,
               progressBar(id = "pb6", value = 20, status = "danger", size = "xs")
        )
      ),
      rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
      title = "Right Sidebar"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
  )
}
```